# Bold or verb text in mathpar

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing a derivation tree using `mathpar` but I'm unsure as to how to markup some words. The derivation tree is for a small programming language, so the premise and/or conclusion contain words I would like to show in bold monospace or something similar (e.g., succ and pred). Normally I would use `\verb+word+` to do this, but I'm unsure how to do it in a `inferrule`. When I use it, `latexmk` gives me trouble. For example, the conclusion of the outer rule (`if ..`) has to be typed in inline math mode for it not to be shown without spacing. I have the `mathpar` manual along side me here, but there is nothing in there about sentences in `inferrule`s.

The code I have is shown below.

```
\begin{mathpar}

\inferrule*[Right=T-If]
    {\inferrule*[Right=T-False]
       { }
       {false : Bool} \\
     \qquad
     \inferrule*[Right=T-Succ]
       {\inferrule*[Right=T-Pred]
          {\inferrule*[Right=T-Zero]{ }{0:Nat}}
          {$pred 0 : Nat$}
       }
       {$succ(pred 0)$} \\
     \qquad 
     \inferrule*[Right=T-Zero]
       { }
       {0: Nat}
    }
  {$if false then succ (pred 0) else 0 : Nat$}
\end{mathpar}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the text to be printed in a monospaced font doesn't have special characters, `\texttt{...}` will suffice. What package provides `mathpar`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Using `\texttt` as @egreg suggests seems to work. For bold you can use `\textbf{}`.